# What is the storage quota for Google Contacts?

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-profiles-api

Today I faced with following error - "Storage quota exceed", while creating new contact. I using Google Contacts API v3.0.
I didn't find any notes about "Storage quota" or API limits at contact docs - https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/

Google contacts doesn't have any api methods for work with storage quota.
I checked gmail quota for this user, and found a lot of free storage.

What does "Storage quota exceed" error mean?
How we can check available storage for user?
Is there any limits for Contacts creation via API?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the actual HTTP response you got back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you think it could be a possibility that you might be hitting your actual contact quota?  Here is an article that explains Google Apps contacts limitations: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1146409.  Can you see if it's the case for you at all?

Comment: Thanks, Emily! We have reached 25 000 limit for one of user!

Answer (score 0):

I only had around 2,000 contacts under "my contacts", but found thousands of doublicates of contacts under "other contacts". Try looking under "other contacts" and see if you have doublicates too.